# Inside each jQuery condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I searched alot  but I couldn't find any solution

I have this code

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var totalprice = 0;
    var ekhizmat = 0;
    var guven = 0;
    var aracprice = parseInt(<?php echo $_POST["aracprice"];?>);
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
        totalprice = totalprice + ekhizmat + guven +parseInt($(this).val(), 10) + aracprice;
    });
    $('#total').text(totalprice);
});
```

I want if I checked then give me this :

```
$('#total').text(totalprice);
```

If I unchecked then give me this :

```
totalprice  = totalprice + aracprice ;
$('#total').text(totalprice);
```

the code :

```js
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
                var totalprice = 0;
                var ekhizmat = 0;
                var guven = 0;
                var aracprice = parseInt(<?php echo $_POST["aracprice"];?>);



                $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
                    totalprice = totalprice + ekhizmat + guven + parseInt($(this).val(), 10) + aracprice;


                });
                $('#total').text(totalprice);



            });

            $('.cb-ek').change(function() {

                var ekhizmat = 0;



                $('.cb-ek:checked').each(function() {
                    ekhizmat = ekhizmat + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    ekhizmat = ekhizmat + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    guven = guven + parseInt($(this).val());

                });
                $('#ekhizmat').text(ekhizmat);
                //                $('#ekhizmat').text(ekhizmat);
                //                $('#guven').text(guven);


            });

            $('.cb-guven').change(function() {

                var guven = 0;



                $('.cb-guven:checked').each(function() {
                    guven = guven + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    ekhizmat = ekhizmat + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    guven = guven + parseInt($(this).val());

                });
                $('#guven').text(guven);
                //                $('#ekhizmat').text(ekhizmat);
                //                $('#guven').text(guven);


            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ar">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/main.css">


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.webui-popover/1.2.1/jquery.webui-popover.min.css"> ...
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.webui-popover/1.2.1/jquery.webui-popover.min.js"></script>



    <body>


        <style>
            .card {
                width: 263px;
                margin-right: -15px;
                float: right;
                text-align: center;
                direction: rtl;
                padding: 15px;
                border-radius: 0;
            }

            .img-full {
                width: 46%;
                transform: translateX(58%) translateY(0%);
            }

            .title-ek {
                font-size: 20px;
                margin-bottom: 18px;
                background: blanchedalmond;
                padding: 10px;
                background: #1e5799;
                background: #861c3b;
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #861c3b 0%, #38145b 100%);
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #861c3b 0%, #38145b 100%);
                background: linear-gradient(to right, #861c3b 0%, #38145b 100%);
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#861c3b', endColorstr='#38145b', GradientType=1);
                color: #fff;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .price-left {
                text-align: left;
                direction: ltr;
                font-weight: bold;
                line-height: 28px;
            }

            .cb-ek {
                bottom: 21px;
                position: absolute;
                right: 20px;
            }

            .head-tile-ek {
                margin-right: -17px;
                margin-top: 30px;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
                font-size: 23px;
                font-weight: 700;
                color: #382e82;
            }

            #baby {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 42px;
                right: 19px;
                color: #861c3b;
            }

            .section-basket {
                z-index: 110;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .section-basket .container {
                background-color: #FDECCD;
                color: #333;
                padding: 20px;
                background-color: #861c3bf5;
                color: #FFF;
                max-width: 930px;
                border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .section-basket .info {
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 16px;
                padding-right: 8px;
            }

            .section-basket .total {
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 20x;

            }

            .section-basket .total .btn {
                margin-right: 20px;
            }

            section-basket .container span {
                color: #333;
                font-size: 100%;
            }

            sub {
                bottom: -0.25em;
            }

            .btn-primary {
                color: #ffffff;
                background-color: #2780e3;
                border-color: #2780e3;
            }

            .btn {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-bottom: 0;
                font-weight: normal;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
                touch-action: manipulation;
                cursor: pointer;
                background-image: none;
                border: 1px solid transparent;
                white-space: nowrap;
                padding: 10px 18px;
                font-size: 15px;
                line-height: 1.42857143;
                border-radius: 0;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
            }

            .btn-primary {
                color: #ffffff;
                background-color: transparent;
                ;
                border-color: #ffffff;
            }

            .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
            .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
            .show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: transparent;
                border-color: #ffffff;
            }

            .btn-primary:hover {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: transparent;
                border-color: #ffffff;
            }

            .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
            .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
            .show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #38145b;
                border-color: #ffffff;
            }

            .space {
                margin-right: 10px;
            }

        </style>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <h2 class="head-tile-ek">الخدمات الإضافية</h2>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">سائق إضافي</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/chauffeur.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">100 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-ek" value="100">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">GPS</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/navigator.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">200 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-ek" value="200">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">مقعد طفل</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/child.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">300 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-ek" value="300">
                            <a href="#" data-title="Title" data-content="Contents..." data-placement="right"><i id="baby" class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a>


                            <script>
                                $('#baby').webuiPopover({

                                    content: 'مناسب للأطفال ذوي الوزن من 9 كيلو إلى 36 كيلو',
                                    placement: 'top',
                                    animation: 'pop'

                                });

                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">سائق</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/chauffeur.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">400 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-ek" value="400">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <h2 class="head-tile-ek">خدمات التأمين</h2>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">أضرار خفيفة</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/car-insurance.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">500 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-guven" value="500">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">أضرار ثقيلة</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/accident.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">600 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-guven" value="600">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">مقعد طفل</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/child.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">400 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-guven" value="400">

                            <script>


                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">سائق إضافي</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/chauffeur.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">200 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-guven" value="200">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <script>
        
        </script>
        <div class="section-basket">
            <div class="container ">



                <div class="total">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitButton"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-fw"></i> المتابعة</button>

                    <span class="price"><span id="total"><?php echo $_POST['aracprice'];?></span> TL</span>
                    <span class="label" dir="rtl">المجموع: </span><span class="space"></span>
                    <i class="fas fa-equals"></i><span class="space"></span>

                    <span id="sigorta" class="price"><span id="guven">0</span> TL</span>
                    <span class="label" dir="rtl">التأمين: </span><span class="space"></span>
                    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i><span class="space"></span>

                    <span class="price"><span id="ekhizmat">0</span> TL</span>
                    <span class="label" dir="rtl">خدمات إضافية: </span><span class="space"></span>
                    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i><span class="space"></span>

                    <span id="arac" class="price"><span><?php echo $_POST['aracprice'];?></span> TL</span>
                    <span class="label" dir="rtl">المركبة: </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    </body>

</html>
```

Simply I want make If and else but I couldnt with each loop
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: You need to bind your `change` event. Like `$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() { ` instead of `$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<script>
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
                var totalprice = parseInt(<?php echo $_POST["aracprice"];?>);
                var ekhizmat = 0;
                var guven = 0;
              

                $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
                    totalprice = totalprice + +ekhizmat + guven + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    ekhizmat = ekhizmat + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    guven = guven + parseInt($(this).val());

                });
                $('#total').text(totalprice);
                //                $('#ekhizmat').text(ekhizmat);
                //                $('#guven').text(guven);


            });

            $('.cb-ek').change(function() {

                var ekhizmat = 0;



                $('.cb-ek:checked').each(function() {
                    ekhizmat = ekhizmat + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    ekhizmat = ekhizmat + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    guven = guven + parseInt($(this).val());

                });
                $('#ekhizmat').text(ekhizmat);
                //                $('#ekhizmat').text(ekhizmat);
                //                $('#guven').text(guven);


            });

            $('.cb-guven').change(function() {

                var guven = 0;



                $('.cb-guven:checked').each(function() {
                    guven = guven + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    ekhizmat = ekhizmat + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    guven = guven + parseInt($(this).val());

                });
                $('#guven').text(guven);
                //                $('#ekhizmat').text(ekhizmat);
                //                $('#guven').text(guven);


            });

        </script>
```

all code :

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ar">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/main.css">


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.webui-popover/1.2.1/jquery.webui-popover.min.css"> ...
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.webui-popover/1.2.1/jquery.webui-popover.min.js"></script>



    <body>


        <style>
            .card {
                width: 263px;
                margin-right: -15px;
                float: right;
                text-align: center;
                direction: rtl;
                padding: 15px;
                border-radius: 0;
            }

            .img-full {
                width: 46%;
                transform: translateX(58%) translateY(0%);
            }

            .title-ek {
                font-size: 20px;
                margin-bottom: 18px;
                background: blanchedalmond;
                padding: 10px;
                background: #1e5799;
                background: #861c3b;
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #861c3b 0%, #38145b 100%);
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #861c3b 0%, #38145b 100%);
                background: linear-gradient(to right, #861c3b 0%, #38145b 100%);
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#861c3b', endColorstr='#38145b', GradientType=1);
                color: #fff;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .price-left {
                text-align: left;
                direction: ltr;
                font-weight: bold;
                line-height: 28px;
            }

            .cb-ek {
                bottom: 21px;
                position: absolute;
                right: 20px;
            }

            .head-tile-ek {
                margin-right: -17px;
                margin-top: 30px;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
                font-size: 23px;
                font-weight: 700;
                color: #382e82;
            }

            #baby {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 42px;
                right: 19px;
                color: #861c3b;
            }

            .section-basket {
                z-index: 110;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .section-basket .container {
                background-color: #FDECCD;
                color: #333;
                padding: 20px;
                background-color: #861c3bf5;
                color: #FFF;
                max-width: 930px;
                border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .section-basket .info {
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 16px;
                padding-right: 8px;
            }

            .section-basket .total {
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 20x;

            }

            .section-basket .total .btn {
                margin-right: 20px;
            }

            section-basket .container span {
                color: #333;
                font-size: 100%;
            }

            sub {
                bottom: -0.25em;
            }

            .btn-primary {
                color: #ffffff;
                background-color: #2780e3;
                border-color: #2780e3;
            }

            .btn {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-bottom: 0;
                font-weight: normal;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
                touch-action: manipulation;
                cursor: pointer;
                background-image: none;
                border: 1px solid transparent;
                white-space: nowrap;
                padding: 10px 18px;
                font-size: 15px;
                line-height: 1.42857143;
                border-radius: 0;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
            }

            .btn-primary {
                color: #ffffff;
                background-color: transparent;
                ;
                border-color: #ffffff;
            }

            .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
            .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
            .show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: transparent;
                border-color: #ffffff;
            }

            .btn-primary:hover {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: transparent;
                border-color: #ffffff;
            }

            .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
            .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
            .show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #38145b;
                border-color: #ffffff;
            }

            .space {
                margin-right: 10px;
            }

        </style>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <h2 class="head-tile-ek">الخدمات الإضافية</h2>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">سائق إضافي</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/chauffeur.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">100 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-ek" value="100">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">GPS</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/navigator.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">200 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-ek" value="200">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">مقعد طفل</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/child.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">300 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-ek" value="300">
                            <a href="#" data-title="Title" data-content="Contents..." data-placement="right"><i id="baby" class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a>


                            <script>
                                $('#baby').webuiPopover({

                                    content: 'مناسب للأطفال ذوي الوزن من 9 كيلو إلى 36 كيلو',
                                    placement: 'top',
                                    animation: 'pop'

                                });

                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">سائق</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/chauffeur.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">400 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-ek" value="400">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <h2 class="head-tile-ek">خدمات التأمين</h2>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">أضرار خفيفة</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/car-insurance.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">500 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-guven" value="500">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">أضرار ثقيلة</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/accident.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">600 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-guven" value="600">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">مقعد طفل</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/child.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">400 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-guven" value="400">

                            <script>


                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="title-ek">سائق إضافي</h3>
                            <img src="../public/icons/chauffeur.svg" alt="" class="img-full" style="float:left">
                            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="price-left" style="float:left">200 TL</div>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" class="cb-guven" value="200">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <script>
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
                var totalprice = parseInt(<?php echo $_POST["aracprice"];?>);
                var ekhizmat = 0;
                var guven = 0;
              

                $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
                    totalprice = totalprice + +ekhizmat + guven + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    ekhizmat = ekhizmat + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    guven = guven + parseInt($(this).val());

                });
                $('#total').text(totalprice);
                //                $('#ekhizmat').text(ekhizmat);
                //                $('#guven').text(guven);


            });

            $('.cb-ek').change(function() {

                var ekhizmat = 0;



                $('.cb-ek:checked').each(function() {
                    ekhizmat = ekhizmat + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    ekhizmat = ekhizmat + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    guven = guven + parseInt($(this).val());

                });
                $('#ekhizmat').text(ekhizmat);
                //                $('#ekhizmat').text(ekhizmat);
                //                $('#guven').text(guven);


            });

            $('.cb-guven').change(function() {

                var guven = 0;



                $('.cb-guven:checked').each(function() {
                    guven = guven + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    ekhizmat = ekhizmat + parseInt($(this).val());
                    //                    guven = guven + parseInt($(this).val());

                });
                $('#guven').text(guven);
                //                $('#ekhizmat').text(ekhizmat);
                //                $('#guven').text(guven);


            });

        </script>
        <div class="section-basket">
            <div class="container ">



                <div class="total">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitButton"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-fw"></i> المتابعة</button>

                    <span class="price"><span id="total"><?php echo $_POST['aracprice'];?></span> TL</span>
                    <span class="label" dir="rtl">المجموع: </span><span class="space"></span>
                    <i class="fas fa-equals"></i><span class="space"></span>

                    <span id="sigorta" class="price"><span id="guven">0</span> TL</span>
                    <span class="label" dir="rtl">التأمين: </span><span class="space"></span>
                    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i><span class="space"></span>

                    <span class="price"><span id="ekhizmat">0</span> TL</span>
                    <span class="label" dir="rtl">خدمات إضافية: </span><span class="space"></span>
                    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i><span class="space"></span>

                    <span id="arac" class="price"><span><?php echo $_POST['aracprice'];?></span> TL</span>
                    <span class="label" dir="rtl">المركبة: </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {

    var totalprice = 0;
    var ekhizmat = 0;
    var guven = 0;
    var aracprice = parseInt(<?php echo $_POST["aracprice"];?>);

    if (this.checked) {
       totalprice = totalprice + ekhizmat + guven +parseInt($(this).val(), 10) + aracprice;
    }else{
       totalprice  = totalprice + aracprice ;
    }

    $('#total').text(totalprice);
}
```

Comment: thanks alot it works fine but there is other problem when I check any thing its give me a value and sum it to the total but if i unchecked one from what i checked it not give me a right total , just give me the total from zero

Comment: you can use `$('#total').val()` instead of `totalPrice`.